# How to convert request-promise get Request to Axios get Request

Tags: node.js, axios, request-promise

This is my request-promise get Request Code
I want to convert this code to Axios get Request

```
let file = rp.get({
  uri: "url",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "message/rfc2822"
  }
}).auth("api", "ap`enter code here`i-key")
/**Access the buffer here**/
file.on('data', (data => {
  console.log("data", data)
  // Here I get blob format data
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios code of your code will be:

```
axios.get("url", {
        headers: {
            Accept: "message/rfc2822"
        },
        auth: {
            username: "api",
            password: "api-key"
        },
        responseType: "stream"
    })
    .then(response => {
        response.data.pipe(concat(data => {
            console.log("data", data);
        }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Comment: I got error with this code , If I remove `response.data.on("data", data => {
            console.log("data", data);
        });` then It return response I mean not getting error , Any solution ?

Comment: What is concat ?

Comment: It concatenates data from a stream into a single buffer. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51108976/node-js-streams-understanding-data-concatenation)

Comment: From Where I have to import ?

Comment: I mean from Where I'm get this concat method ? Is it any inbuild method ?

Comment: I'm working in Node.js , Is it available in Node.js ?

Comment: Yes you need to install package from npm for use concat facility. [Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat-stream)  `npm install concat-stream`

Comment: Can we use ` import { concat } from "lodash";` ? Which is use from lodash ?

Comment: yes you can try both and use preferable option among from both.